# How deploy a camel route as jar to wildfly without the huge camel patch? There is no Galleon Camel layer

Tags: apache-camel, wildfly, jbossfuse

I build my own wildfy server with galleon and it works perfectly. I searched for an example to add a apache camel feature pack to the server, but there is no example or documentation. Since [wildfly camel patch 10.0.0](https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel/releases/tag/10.0.0) it should support galleon, but galleon could not find/resolve a wildfly-camel feature pack.

When I patch a normal wildfly-16 with the camel patch, it is three times bigger than my own provisioned wildfly. I only need a rest endpoint, prepare a JMS Message and want to send it via JMS to an EJB container that runs on wildfly. I want to realize this with camel/fuse,  but I do not need all the other stuff like hawtio, switchyard and so on. Running a camel route with `mvn camel:run` is so easy and slim.

Is there a best practice to deploy a camel route in a singe war or jar without the huge wildfly camel patch? A feature pack location for the camel galleon layer would helps also, if there exist one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy the [camel-example-servlet-tomcat](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/camel-3.0.0-M4/examples/camel-example-servlet-tomcat) example project to camel and the project runs fine in wildfly16. The example war archive has a size of ~12MB, this is very small. I need a rest endpoint and a JMS connection, so I will create a web project and will add the camel dependencies like in the example.